# OnRowDataBound click event open another gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 2 `gridviews`. The first one is visible and second one is not.

What I want is:- When I click on any row of the first `gridview`, the relevant data should get open in the another `gridview`.

I haven't done this before. Here is my html

```
<cc1:Grid ID="GridFirst" runat="server" FolderStyle="../Styles/Grid/style_12" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowColumnResizing="true" Width="40%" ShowFooter="true"
                    ShowHeader="true" OnRowDataBound="GridFirst_RowDataBound" AllowRecordSelection="true">
                    <Columns>
                        <cc1:Column ID="Column1" DataField="Sr_NO" Wrap="true" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Sr No"
                            Width="4%">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="Column2" DataField="Type" Wrap="true" HeaderText="Type" Width="10%">
                        </cc1:Column>
                        <cc1:Column ID="Column3" DataField="Date" Wrap="true" HeaderText="Date" Width="10%">
                        </cc1:Column>
                    </Columns>
                </cc1:Grid>
```

On `GridFirst_RowDataBound` event

```
protected void GridFirst_RowDataBound(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRowEventArgs e)
{
  // open second gridview with relevant data here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GridView SelectedValue property if your GridView has DataKeyNames property set as follows:

```
protected void grdClient_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(grdClient.SelectedValue != null)
     {
         Project ObjProject = new Project();
         int userClientID. = int .Parse(grdClient.SelectedValue.ToString());

         ObjProject.UserClientID = userClientID;

         grdProject.DataSource = ObjProject.GetProjectList();
         grdProject.DataBind();
     }
 }
```

Initially make the second GridView visible false and OnRowClick make it visible true.

Comment: What have you got I mean any issue?

Comment: actually, I am using `Obout` grid and there is no property as `SelectedIndexChanged` as such. SO unable to get the debugger with your code..

Comment: Try to use OnSelectedIndexChanged in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

The RowDataBound event is fired each time a row has been filled with data (basically when you call gridview.DataBind());

It is not here you want to put the code to display the second gridview on a user event.

I think you should use RowCommand with a parameter.

In your aspx :

Add to your gridview :

`OnRowCommand="myMethod_Rowcommand"`

Try first with a clickable button on each row (and when you click on it, it will trigger the command), add these attributes :

`CommandName="DisplaySecondGrid" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("yourId") %>'`

Then in your code behind

`if(e.CommandName == "DisplaySecondGrid")
    {
        var id = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        var myData = repository.GetData(id);
        secondGridView.DataSource = myData;
        secondGridView.DataBind();
        secondGridView.Visible = true;
    }`

Something like this should do the trick

Comment: can you show the aspx of the gridview ? as what I have to add in gridview